# How to define id of Object generated from 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have generated an object from 2D array.

And then, how to define unique id through each object?
"?" in the following code needs to edit.

```
data = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "b"]
]

for (i in data) {
    data[i] = data[i].map(c => ({id: ?, char:c}) )
}

console.log(data)
```

The following result format is assumed.

```
[
  0: {
    0:{
      "id": "?",
      "char": "a"
    },
    1:{
      "id": "?",
      "char": "b"
    },
    2:{
      "id": "?",
      "char": "c"
    }
  },

  1: {
    0:{
      "id": "?",
      "char": "a"
    },
    1:{
      "id": "?",
      "char": "b"
    }
  }
]
```

I thought iterating, but it seems like to needs to flatten the object,
so I could not use it because I did not want to change the format of the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create count variable to make the id

```js
data = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "b"]
]
let count = 0;
for (let i in data) {
    data[i] = data[i].map(c => {
        count ++;
      return {id: count, char:c}
    } )
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map single objects inside and assign the arrays to an object. Take the same approach for the outer array.

```js
var data = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b"]],
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        data.map(a => Object.assign(
            {},
            a.map(char => ({ id: '?', char }))
        ))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you want *objects* rather than arrays, you won't be able to use `.map`. Because you have both parent objects and nested objects, you might use `reduce` twice:

```js
const data = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "b"]
];
const output = data.reduce((a, arr, i) => {
  a[i] = arr.reduce((obj, char, j) => {
    obj[j] = { char, id: '?' };
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```